# texarea inserting newlines when pasting text in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, textarea

I'm getting a strange behavior with textareas in chrome (linux and windows).

1. Open this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sonic1980/N4vUS/
2. Copy the 3 lines of text into the textarea.
3. Between each line multiple newlines appear.

Why? How can I avoid this?

The textarea has this style:

```
textarea {
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
}​
```

Comment: To add to this, Firefox displays them correctly while IE9 displays no line breaks at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty jQuery workaround, but works for me.
This catches the `paste` event and removes all blank lines.

```
$('#myTextArea').bind('paste', function(e){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var text = '';
        $($('#myTextArea').val().split('\n')).each(function(i,v){
            v = $.trim(v);
            if (v.length > 0) text+= v+'\n';
        });
        console.log(text);
        $('#myTextArea').val(text);
    },1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue with Safari in the past, and believe it was a bug with WebKit. I don't know whether it has been fixed for the current Chrome releases, but it seems to be fixed for Safari.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/codemirror/m0LeyKF6LcE